# Repetição de elementos

Tags: c

Estou com dificuldade para gerar como saída a quantidade de elementos repetidos no vetor. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N, i, temp, repetidos = 1;

    int *v1;

    printf ("Entre com N: ");
    scanf ("%d", &N);

    v1 = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof (int));

    temp = v1[0];

    for (i=1; i < M + 1; ++i){
        scanf ("%d", &v1[i]);

        if (v1[i] == temp){
            repetidos++;

            if (repetidos > 1){
                printf ("%d", repetidos);
            }
            temp = v1[i];
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o critério para determinar se é repetido? Qualquer número que aparecer pelo menos duas vezes é todas as ocorrências são consideradas repetidas?

Comment: queria como saída só a quantidade de números que repetem e não quantas vezes repetiram. por exemplo, vetor: 1, 2 , 3, 3, 2 com saída: 2.

Comment: a saída é 2 porque ocorre repetição com o 3 e c/ o 2?

Comment: exatamente! Desculpe-me se não fui claro

Comment: EU acho que é é bem mais complicado que isso, preciso pensar, mas acho que só se usar um vetor auxiliar.

Comment: estou tentando diminuir o problema em partes pois estou com dificuldades para entender como resolvê-lo. talvez com o enunciado fique mais claro pra você entender, certo?

Comment: Vai precisar dos dados entradas depois, ou é só contar os grupos repetidos e morreu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer a quantidade de números que se repetem no vetor. Exemplo: {1, 2, 3, 3, 3} deve retornar que 1 número se repete (o três). O vetor {1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5} deve retornar quatro, pois quatro valores se repetem no vetor (1, 2, 3 e 4).

No seu caso, não ficou claro se o vetor está ordenado. Portanto implementei o quick sort para fazer isso, o que facilita bastante a resolução do problema.

Além disso, não ficou claro se o vetor original poderia ser modificado. Por este motivo, criei uma cópia dele (`v2`) e a ordenei. A variável `repeticoesNumero` está recebendo o número de vezes que um valor aparece no vetor. Se este valor for maior que um, significa que o valor se repete, e assim incremento a variável `resposta`, que ao final da execução terá o número de elementos que se repetem no vetor. Abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void quickSort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int j;

    if(l < r)  {
        j = partition( a, l, r);
        quickSort(a, l, j-1);
        quickSort(a, j+1, r);
    }
}

int partition(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int pivot, i, j, t;
    pivot = a[l];
    i = l;
    j = r+1;

    while(1) {
        do
            ++i;
        while(a[i] <= pivot && i <= r);
        do
            --j;
        while(a[j] > pivot);
        if( i >= j ) break;
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    t = a[l];
    a[l] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
    return j;
}
int main() {
    int n, i, temp, repeticoesNumero, resposta = 0;
    int *v1, *v2;

    printf ("Entre com n: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    v1 = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    v2 = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof (int));

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
        v2[i] = v1[i];
    }

    quickSort(v2, 0, n - 1);

    temp = v2[0];
    repeticoesNumero = 1;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (v2[i] == temp) repeticoesNumero++;
        else {
            if (repeticoesNumero > 1) resposta++;
            temp = v2[i];
            repeticoesNumero = 1;
        }
    }
    if (repeticoesNumero > 1) resposta++;
    printf("%i numero(s) se repete(m) no vetor.\n", resposta);
}
```

Espero que seja isso!

**Apenas uma observação**: no seu código há um `M` no laço `for`. Eu acredito que tenha sido apenas um erro de digitação e o valor original seja `N`. Minha implementação está considerando que foi um erro de digitação.

Answer (score 2):

Eu farei um código tão simples quanto dá para um iniciante que não sabe e não pode fazer coisas mais complexas. Em um código profissional seria bem diferente, haveria funções, uma estrutura de dados adequada para isso, provavelmente com bits e outras otimizações.

Eu não faria com ordenação por causa do custo e complexidade da implementação.

Conforme eu disse em comentários precisaria de um vetor auxiliar para indicar se há repetição. Espero que os requisitos estejam corretos, fiz de acordo com o que deu para entender.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int N, repetidos = 0;
    printf("Entre com N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int *v1 = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
    int *aux = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
    int *flag = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf ("%d", &v1[i]);
        int achou = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cont; j++) {
            if (v1[i] == aux[j]) {
                flag[j] = 1;
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!achou) {
            aux[cont] = v1[i];
            flag[cont++] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) repetidos += flag[i];
    if (repetidos > 0) printf ("\n%d repetidos", repetidos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Af1h5g). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cgfvfvhg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Unique.c).

Se puder descartar o vetor pode simplificar um pouco:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int N, repetidos = 0;
    printf("Entre com N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int *v1 = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
    int *flag = malloc(N * sizeof (int));
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int valor = 0;
        scanf ("%d", &valor);
        int achou = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cont; j++) {
            if (valor == v1[j]) {
                flag[j] = 1;
                achou = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!achou) {
            v1[cont] = valor;
            flag[cont++] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) repetidos += flag[i];
    if (repetidos > 0) printf ("\n%d repetidos", repetidos);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dN7ODY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kmcxvzio-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Unique2.c).

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o problema dele, esse código não funciona. N=4 e {1,1,1,1} não imprime nada e deveria ser 1. N=5 e {1,2,3,3,2} dá 1 repetido, mas a saída deveria ser 2, de acordo com o comentário do Leko.

Comment: @eightShirt é, eu esqueci de fazer uma última alteração quando estava testando, agora está certo, obrigado. Pode ser visto em http://ideone.com/h5KHsL e http://ideone.com/ez7A56

Comment: É uma pena não ter erro mais e ter um negativo na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Para encontrar o nº de repetidos, há algumas opções:

- Use um vetor booleano também de tamanho N para guardar casas visitadas. Para cada casa do vetor original, faça uma busca nas casas restantes procurando por repetidas. Se encontrá-las, indique as posições no booleano e incremente o contador de repetidas (apenas uma vez). Ao continuar a busca, ignore as casas já visitadas.
- Ou, ordene o vetor. Então basta varrê-lo e ver se há casas adjacentes iguais. Caso positivo, incremente o contador e continue na próxima casa não repetida.